# How can I receive multicast UDP packets asynchronously in Golang?

Tags: networking, go, udp, multicast, udpclient

I am trying to create an application to receive multicast UDP packets. This application does not only listen for incoming packets but also does many other tasks as well. So, I wanted to keep receiving part async. 
I program in Golang.

Any help would be appreciated, happy coding..

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think you could put the listener into a for declaration and every time that you receive a package from the listener you could execute what do you want in a goroutine.

an example can be [here](http://www.minaandrawos.com/2016/05/14/udp-vs-tcp-in-golang/) and look in the section **SERVER IMPLEMENTATION**

Comment: Thank you. How about taking the listener into a goroutine? Is it ok?

Comment: Well, It depends. As you mentioned before your program does also others things and you don't want the application waiting just for the packets, right? if so, yeah you can put in a goroutine ;) otherwise, I think is better let in the main thread.

Comment: After taking the listener into a goroutine, is it a good idea to spawn (call) another goroutine to process the received bytes inside the listener routine?

Comment: I cannot see why not, but just pay attention to the concurrency that might have.